# sending json from javascript to controller in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, codeigniter

im new in codeigniter so i wanna send a json from javascript to a controller usin ajax here its the code of javascript

```
    var text = '{ "employees" : [' +
                '{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },' +
                '{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },' +
                '{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" },'+
                '{  "algo": "7"} ]}';
    var obj = JSON.parse(text);

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    obj.employees[1].firstName + " " + obj.employees[3].algo;


    $(document).on("click", "#boton", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/css/index/index/click",
                data : "{'places':'" + obj + "'}",
                contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                fail : function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
    });
});
```

and here is my code of my controller:

```
<?php


class Index extends CI_Controller {


    function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();

    }
    public function Index()
    {
        $this -> load -> view('index/principal');

    }

    public function click(){
         $places = $this->input->post('places'); 
         print_r(json_decode($places));
    }
}
```

its posible in the way that im doing? or there is other way to do it?

thx

Comment: url of `window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/css/index/index/click"` is unnecessary, could easily just be `"/css/index/index/click"` which assumes the current protocol and host anyway

Comment: Looks in general fine, I'm guessing you are going to want to just put in the plain json string instead of the parsed object. Have you tried what you wrote here? Are you getting errors or something unexpected?

Comment: im debuggin with the firebug debug when i try it i have no errors but noting happends, i want to alert the json from the controller, in that way i will know how to process the data

Comment: First check ajax call is working or not, if working then simply `echo json_encode($places)`